# Can't get connection to socket server

Tags: socket.io

I'm fairly new to a lot of this stuff and am trying to figure it out.

I have a hosted domain at `<my.domain.com>`. I host a game at this address that users can go to that address and the game loads in the browser for them.

On the same server I am running an Express nodejs (we'll call this `HTTP SERVER`) server to receive HTTP requests.

Also on the same server I am running a socket server using the Socket.io (we'll call this `SOCKET SERVER`) library.

`HTTP SERVER` can connect to `SOCKET SERVER` via `localhost:<port>` and they can communicate back and forth. I can send requests from my mobile device to `HTTP SERVER` which forwards those request to `SOCKET SERVER` and get a response back on the mobile device.

My problem now is I need to create another connection to `SOCKET SERVER` from my hosted game at `<my.domain.com>`. However, when I attempt to connect to `localhost:<port>` like I do from `HTTP SERVER` I get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. I am assuming this has to do with with the host name being different. I've attempted to add

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
});
```

But that doesn't seem to help. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Socket server app.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
});

server.listen(8082);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`Socket server 'connection' event`);
});
```

Code in `HTTP SERVER` that does properly connect and send/receive messages

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:8082');

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(`HTTP server - 'connect' event to socket server`);
});
```

This is a javascript file that the game loads as an add-on. Hooks is provided by the game as an EventEmitter. I do not have direct access to the HTML pages the game displays, though I can manipulate them via this javascript add-on file.

```
let socket;

// a game hook when it's initialized
Hooks.on("init", function() {
        // don't have direct access to game pages, so create a script tag and load
        // the socket.io client library
        const scriptRef = document.createElement('script');
        scriptRef.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        scriptRef.setAttribute('onload', 'window.socketLibraryLoaded()');
        scriptRef.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js');
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptRef);
});

// handler for when library is loaded
window.socketLibraryLoaded = () => {
        log('Socket library loaded');

        // i assume this address is wrong since the host of the game is <my.domain.com> and it's trying to connect to localhost
        socket = io('https://localhost:8082');
        socket.on('connect', () => {
                log('Connected to socket server');
        });
        socket.on('connect_error', error => {
                log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Why do you loading script outside, can't you just write that into your html file?

Comment: I will edit my post to clarify a little, the HTML I mentioned is really a JS file that the game loads as an add-on. So I don't have 'direct' access to the HTML the game is displaying, though I can manipulate it with JS.

Comment: I see, so is `window.socketLibraryLoaded` actually working? if so probably your `io("localhost:8082")` is the problem then

Comment: It is working yep, I can see the console log when that happens. I think it's because the host of the game is 'my.domain.com' and i'm trying to connect to localhost, but the socket server doesn't have any error event that I can get more details on why it's not allowing the connection, and on the client side it just says ERR_CONNETION_REFUSED

Comment: can you just try to connect with `io();` like that, usually it works if you don't need to specify a port. If needed then maybe `io(window.location.href+PORT);` ?

Comment: I have tried, that and in the client side then, I DOget the connected message, but the server doesn't print out it's connected message in response so I'm not exactly sure how Socket.io works with that because then sending messages back and forth doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216174/discussion-between-halil-cakar-and-kamcknig).

Comment: I've found other articles that say they used the NPM package named 'cors' to solve their problems, but no matter what I do I can't get it to  work. I have set up NGINX finally to forward requests to the socket server and I'm not actually getting a proper CORS error response that rather than the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, but no matter how i configure the cors NPM package or any other way that I've found to configure headers, it still won't connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after banging my head on the wall for more than 10 hours over this I finally found the issue. And of course a simple user error.

The CORs error wasn't really the problem. I was getting that error because the NGINX proxy was erroring which caused the proper headers not to get sent back so the browser showed that error.

The issue was that in one place in my NGINX configuration I was using `127.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`